# Laravel composer.json fully istallation

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Is there any way to install laravel from only composer.json file by using

```
composer install
```

command. If i just copy composer.json from existing project it creates only vendor directory, but not app, database, etc.
I just want to load all laravel core files, project file structure and my custom package by using install command of composer.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is to globally install the laravel installer as mentioned in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7 and then do `laravel new <project name>` . Composer will not install the boilerplate automatically. You can also do `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <project name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find solution for this, maybe it's impossible. 
So, i just create my package and manually copy my custom composer.json to project.

Answer (score 1):

You can install laravel with the command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <project_name>` if you only want to use composer, this command is mandatory since it creates the directories you want.

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

Create a new laravel project or clone an old project from git. Then replace/update the composer.json, then run `composer update`, if its a new project  or `composer install`, if you cloned a repo